# How do i get to dynamically refresh JSON data in an EJS tag

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently working on an node/express app that shows several informations about the ISS.
I'm using an API shared by the NASA returning JSON data.

I want the data to be updated dynamically on my page using EJS, without the need to refresh it. let's say every 1000ms.

Here's my actual code to get the ISS's current Longitude and Latitude:

Server side:

```
app.get("/iss", function(req, res){
   var url = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json";
   request(url, function(err, response, body){
       if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
          var data = JSON.parse(body);
          res.render("ISS", {data: data});
       }
   });
});
```

Client side :

```
<div class="ui main text inverted container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">Where is the ISS ?</div>
    <p>Longitude : <%= data["iss_position"].longitude %> </p>
    <p>Latitude : <%= data["iss_position"].latitude %> </p>
</div>
```

I've heard about Socket.io but i don't know if it would be optimized for my need. Also, can i get it to work by using `setInterval()`function ?
If yes, can you help me with that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try using Ajax calls in  client side javascript? That what they are for - dynamically refresh part of the page without reloading it. But you will need to create an api which will provide the json data

Comment: I did not, i'm going to check that out. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample api call for iss endpoint

```
app.get("/iss", function(req, res){
       var url = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json";
       request(url, function(err, response, body){
           if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
              var data = JSON.parse(body);
              res.send(data);
           }
       });
    });
```

Client side code-

```
<div class="ui main text inverted container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">Where is the ISS ?</div>
    <p>Longitude :<span id="longitude"> <%= data["iss_position"].longitude %> </span></p>
    <p>Latitude : <%= data["iss_position"].latitude %> </p>
</div>
```

Assuming you are using jQuery

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
   "url":<base_url>+"/iss",
   "success":function(data){
      $("#longitude").html(data.iss_position.longitude);
   },
   "error":function(error){
   //handle error here
   }
})
</script>
```

> I want the data to be updated dynamically on my page using EJS,
>   without the need to refresh it. let's say every 1000ms.

You may need to call the Ajax function using setInterval to update send the request every 1000ms

Code for setInterval

```
<script>

setInterval(function(){

     $.ajax({
       "url":<base_url>+"/iss",
       "success":function(data){
          $("#longitude").html(data.iss_position.longitude);
       },
       "error":function(error){
       //handle error here
       }
    })

}, 1000);

</script>
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      "url": "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json",

      "success": function(data) {
        $("#longitude").html(data.iss_position.longitude);
      },
      "error": function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="longitude">
</span>
```

You can check the snippet above and see the longitude updating.

Comment: Thanks Santosh, it's helping a lot !
Can you just show me, if you have a moment, how you would use the `setInterval()` In this situation please ?

Comment: The AJAX call and setInterval work great. But my problem now is that the data stored inside of `$("#longitude").html(data.iss_position.longitude);` is always the same.
On the page, the data is refreshed but always the same.

Comment: Can you check what data are you getting from iss server. If the data from iss server is same, then its not code issue.

Comment: The data is dynamic, if i manually refresh the page, the data is updating.

Comment: And the data from your server /iss endpoint api is also dynamic right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you have seen my server side code. I didn't change it

Comment: Can you share your server url

Comment: Do you know Cloud9 ? you can sign up here so i can show you my workspace

Comment: You can print console logs on the success callback of ajax request. Check if you are getting same data.Sadly I am not near my machine, so cannot sign up right now

Comment: Data is updating inside of the AJAX request and updating inside of `.html(data.iss_position.longitude)` BUT not on the page !

Comment: You have added the <span id="longitude">  as mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: Yes of course, for exemple if i use `append.` instead of `html.` it will append the same value over and over every 1000ms into my paragraph

Comment: Please move this discussion to chat. Also can you share jsfiddle regarding this so that I can see the code?

Comment: I would love to move this discussion into chat, sadly i can't (don't have enough reputation).
Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L1acjtf6/

Comment: I have added the running code snippet in answer. Click on run and see the output

Comment: Thanks for your help Santosh.